# ValueError while extracting data form a dataframe using boolean conditions

Tags: pandas, valueerror

I am trying to extract a  dataframe from the built-in seaborn dataset diamond that satisfies two conditions :

- i) The cut is 'ideal'
- ii) The color is 'E'.

The code snippet is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
diam = sns.load_dataset("diamonds")

cut_col = diam[(diam['cut'] == "Ideal") and (diam['color'] == "E"]
```

This gives me the following ValueError:

```
File "C:\Users\logic\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1555, in __nonzero__
    self.__class__.__name__

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

But if I replace the logical operator 'and' with the bitwise operator '&', the code runs fine. Can anyone explain the reason behind this? Why the logical-AND operator does not work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same as you would do in `if` statement, so use:

```
cut_col = diam[(diam['cut'] == "Ideal")&(diam['color'] == "E")]
```

For more info check out [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).